# Code behind (.cs file) vs compiled .Dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, code-behind, bigcommerce

I have a client that I created a custom app for that integrates with BigCommerce. The question I have is since I do not want the client to have access to the .CS files for codebehind, do I have to deploy those as well, or can I just upload the .DLL file? If I can, what needs to be done to accomplish this.

Comment: http://www.bigcommerce.com/

Answer (score 0):

you just need to "publish" the project and it will already move just the files it needs to run.

It is basically dll, .aspx, .css, .js etc ... and NO .cs files

Answer (score 0):

If securing your code is your concern, then the compilation to a DLL will not really buy you too much security, as non-obfuscated code will be easily decompiled by [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

To get some level of code security from prying eyes wanting to steal your logic, then you need to use an code obfuscation tool like [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=smartassembly&gclid=CNqujN-qtbgCFRGg4AodnhMAig)

Answer (score 0):

Publish it or make a installer is the best way. :)